# how to restart docker container based on a log line?

Tags: logging, docker

I want to automatically restart my docker container when a specific line appears in the log.

For example when I do `docker logs xxx`, I see the following error:

```
RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: example.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When this appears in the log I want to automatically restart this docker image.

Thanks!

Comment: Not only does this sound like an awful hack, it sounds like youre suggesting someone provide you with code or a tool that would do it for you.

Comment: Indeed an awful hack, atm no clue how to solve the rootcause see also http://serverfault.com/questions/828102/no-connection-after-openvpn-restart-after-connection-reset

Comment: I think you need to stop PID 1 to stop the container. To do this based on a log line, I think this needs to be done from the application itself putting these logs.